# How to remove The "ObjectId" around the _id in the MogoDB object and log the object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have created an Object in MongoDB.

```
{
 _id : new ObjectId("62181c392c33d3fc59f55ddc"),
name: Escalade,
Brand: Cadillac

}
```

I want to log the object without ObjectId in the _id

```
{
  _id : "62181c392c33d3fc59f55ddc";
 name: Escalade,
Brand: Cadillac

}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why do you care? Where do you log it to?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/

Answer (score 0):

When you add a value in mongodb, in a mongo db collection, it automatically makes a field name _id that is used as a primary key.

Think of it this way. This is how mongo knows the difference between an entry and an other entry

ex:

```
{
 _id : "62181c392c33d3fc59f55ddc";
 name: Escalade,
 Brand: Cadillac
}
{
 _id : "62181c392c33d3fc59f55ddf";
 name: Escalade,
 Brand: Cadillac
}
```

The first Escalade (for mongo) is different from the second Escalade

The only way to get rid of this "_id", is to declare it, when you make the entry.

For example make an entry like this:

```
{
 _id : "1";
 name: some_name,
 Brand: some_brand
}
```

The new entry will have your own _id and mongo will know that "some_name" has the _id of 1

You can search furthermore here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Specifically, when you leave this field ("_id") empty, mongo just inputs an object Id variable. So, you cannot remove it, just declare the "_id" as a string or an integer, basically anything but not an array